# API Platform - Data persister - Can't create new user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm currently trying out API Platform & I'm currently having a problem with my Data Persister when I try to create (post) a new user.

This is my User entity :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

/**

 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *          },
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') and object == user"},
 *          "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"}
 *     },
 *     attributes={
 *     "fetchEager": false,
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user.read"}},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user.write"}}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({
     *     "user.read"
     * })
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups({
     *     "user.read",
     *     "user.write"
     * })
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Groups({
     *     "user.read",
     *     "user.write"
     * })
     */

    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @Groups({
     *     "user.write"
     * })
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = [];
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = Carbon::now();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

And here's my Data Persister :

```
<?php


namespace App\DataPersister;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserDataPersister implements DataPersisterInterface
{
    private $userPasswordEncoder;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder)
    {
        $this->userPasswordEncoder = $userPasswordEncoder;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function supports($data): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof User;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $data
     */
    public function persist($data)
    {
        if ($data->getPlainPassword()) {
            $data->setPassword(
                $this->userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPlainPassword())
            );
        }

        $this->entityManager->persist($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    public function remove($data)
    {
        $this->entityManager->remove($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

When I try to update (put) a user or delete (delete) one, my Data Persister does it's job correctly.
However, when I try to create a new user, I get this error :
"password:  this value should not be null."

Also, here's the content of my request

```
{"email":"new.user@domain.com","plainPassword":"abcdefg","password":"abcdefg","roles":["ROLE_USER"]}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you !

Comment: Try and put a break point when you call `$data->setPassword(...)` in your User Persister class. I can take a guess by saying it will probably break successfully, which could mean that you gonna need a `user.write` annotation group above your `$password` property.

Comment: ... Oh my God... How did I not see that.
Thanks a lot !